# Is there some objective-c magic to obtain the index of the outside array in a search?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an array that contains arrays. The container is like this:

```
NSArray *container = @[

@[ @(12), @(23), @(34), @(11)],  // index 0 
@[ @(32), @(12), @(12), @(78)],  // index 1
@[ @(14), @(97), @(45), @(82)],  // index 2
@[ @(67), @(20), @(46), @(12)],  // index 3

]
```

all the internal arrays have the same number of elements.

Suppose I want to see if @(45) is on stored on any array inside the container and if positive, to obtain the index of that subarray, in that case index 2 (see comments in code).

I know how to do that by using enumerations. What I am looking for is if there is some magic that can be used to do that with less code (I know objective-c has a lot of magic obscure commands) to do all kind of things).

I know I can do something like this, to get the array, given the element

```
NSString *search = @(45);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF CONTAINS %@", search];
NSArray *array = [container filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
NSLog(@"result: %@", array);
```

but what about the index of that array on the container?

thanks

Comment: What if two sub-arrays contain the element you are searching for? I am asking because there is obviously a reason for your having arrays of arrays and this could be made easier by having an array of objects that manage their arrays and which could have methods that do what you need them to do. But it all depends on reason for you doing what you are doing.

Comment: not the case, during the subarray creation process, I enforce that one element is just present in one subarray. They are separated in subarrays because they represent different things that use their elements in separate and that makes code simple for that task.

Comment: There is no magic here (but there is documentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method of `NSArray` can return first index of the object that match the criteria:

```
int value = 12;
NSUInteger idx = [container indexOfObjectPassingTest:
    ^BOOL (NSArray* subArray, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return *stop = [subArray containsObject:@(value)];
}];
```

Comment: WHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOAAAAAAAAAAAAA!!!!!!!! FANTASTIC! I knew some magic command would show!!!! You are a genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of an object in the array using [**indexOfObject:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject%3a) method.

You can do it like:

```
NSString *search = @(45);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF == %@", search];

// Filtered is an array which contains the result (Means the filtered array contains the index 2 array - array of array)
NSArray *filtered = [container filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];

// Using `indexOfObject:` method for getting the result
NSLog(@"Index %d", [container indexOfObject:[filtered objectAtIndex:0]]);
```

Comment: getting this error on the filtered line: uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection 1 (not a collection)'

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper: My mistake, I used your code instead of mine, Please check my updated code

Comment: @DesperateDeveloper: Actually the condition of NSPredicate should be `ANY SELF == %@`, I copied that code from your question and forgot to change the condition :)